# GAE Launcher (Python) could not start

Tags: google-app-engine, numpy

I believe this is related a number of python packages I have recently installed environmental variables that I have changed. I have re-installed Numpy and GAE, which did not help. So any suggestions on this? Thanks!

The GAE log indicated that the failure was lined to file import

```
2013-12-11 11:45:20 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8094', '--admin_port=8004', 'D:\\Dropbox\\ubertool_src']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 197, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 193, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 27, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    ranf = random = sample = random_sample
NameError: name 'random_sample' is not defined
2013-12-11 11:45:21 (Process exited with code 1)
```

#### Update

just did a little test.
I can run `from numpy import random`
but if I run `import random`
The error msg is:

```
>>> import random
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    ranf = random = sample = random_sample
NameError: name 'random_sample' is not defined
```

### Update

The problem is solved after removing `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy` (I am not sure how this was added) from `PYTHONPATH` in `Environmental Variable`